# Why won't my execution time be written in a file?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using the Chrono library to calculate the execution time of my particular line of code. I am able to calculate the execution time but when I try to write that in a file I am getting various errors.
The errors I am getting are:

no match for operator <<

**cannot convert diffe to type const unsigned char***

Here's an instance of my code

```
    int main ()
{   

    ofstream plot;
    plot.open("graph.txt");

    srand((unsigned)time(0));    


        int n = 250;
        std::cout <<"The size of the array is:" << n << std::endl;
        std::cout <<"\n";

        plot << n;
        int *arr = new int (sizeof(int)*n);

        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {

            int number = (rand()%1000+1);
            arr[i] = number;
        }
        std::cout << "The array provided is:" << std::endl;
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            std::cout << arr[i] << " ";

        }
        std::cout << "\n";
        std::cout<<"\n";

                auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
                Selectionsort (arr,n);
                auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
                auto diffe = end-start; 
                double  a = (double ) diff;
                plot << diff;
                std::cout << "The execution time for average case is:" <<
                std::cout << chrono::duration <double, milli> (diffe).count() << " ms" << std::endl;
```

plot << diffe; 
is the reason I am getting an error. What I am doing in this code is calculating the execution time for best, worst and average case and transferring the size of the array and data to a file to plot the graph. I have no experience in using the Chrono library before

Comment: Remove the type declaration from the output statement: `std::cout << diffe.count() << " ms" << std::endl;`

Comment: You don't have a declaration of `diff`. Did you mean to use `diffe`?

Comment: `new int (sizeof(int)*n)` allocates *one* `int` with the value `sizeof(int)*n`.

Comment: Recommend cleaning this up and producing a [mcve]. If making the MCVE doesn't expose your problem to you, edit the question to include the MCVE.

Comment: Yes, I meant to use diffe. Sorry for the typo but even if I use diffe I am still getting erro

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the duration can be solved with `duration_cast` and the other problem is the line `int *arr = new int (sizeof(int)*n);` which, as molbdnilo noticed, allocates only one `int` with the value of `sizeof(int)*n`. You may also want to use a better random number generator. Suggestions in code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector> // std::vector
#include <random> // std::random

int main ()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 generator(rd()); // seed a prng
    // and create a distribution object:
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> rnd_dist(1, 1000); // [1,1000]

    // you can open the file directly like this:
    std::ofstream plot("graph.txt");
    // and check if it was opened successfully:
    if(!plot) {
        std::clog << "couldn't open file\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // I'll use a std::random generator instead of this:
    // srand((unsigned)time(0));

    int n = 250;
    std::cout <<"The size of the array is:" << n << "\n\n";

    plot << n; // you probably want  << "\n";  here
    // You had:
    //   int *arr = new int (sizeof(int)*n);
    // It should have been:
    //   int *arr = new int[n];
    // but the below is better since you don't have to delete[] it manually:
    std::vector<int> arr(n);

    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        arr[i] = rnd_dist(generator);
    }

    std::cout << "The array provided is:\n";
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    // Edit: changed to high_resolution_clock
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    // the below call works, but consider changing the signaure of your Selectionsort() to:
    // void Selectionsort(std::vector<int>& arr);
    // The "n" is available via "arr.size();"
    Selectionsort(arr.data(), arr.size());
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    // diffe duration_cast fix:
    auto diffe = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end-start);
    plot << diffe.count(); // you probably want  << "\n";  here
    std::cout << "The execution time for average case is: " << diffe.count() << " ms\n";
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your code. I finally can execute my code and write the execution time in a file but the problem is that it shows that the execution time is 0 milli seconds.

Comment: @AyushPoudel It could be that your `Selectionsort` is too fast for the steady clock to notice. I changed to `high_resolution_clock` in the answer. Perhaps that'll notice a diff. You can also try to do a `duration_cast` to `std::chrono::microseconds` to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I changed it to high_resolution_clock and also increased the size of my array drastically but it still gives me 0 ms. If I do :

auto diffe = end-start;
I do get the time in millisecond but when I try to write it to my file using
plot << diffe.count()  it gives me numbers like 440490. And I don't know how I am to interpret the number.

Comment: Have you checked that the array is really sorted afterwards?

Comment: Yes,the array is sorted I actually made some edit in my previous comment. Can you please check that

Comment: So, `std::cout << diffe.count() << "\n";` and `plot << diffe.count() << "\n";` (without changing `diffe` inbetween) gives different results? That's strange. `440490` looks like microseconds (0.4 seconds).

Comment: ... or did you perhaps change `n` to `440`? If you did, that's the first part of what you see in the file. Look at the comments I made at both `plot << ` lines.

Comment: Is there any way I can send you my .cpp file? I just can't seem to figure it out? How can it be in microseconds when we have specified it to be millisecond?

Comment: You can post the file at [ideone](https://ideone.com/) for example. Did you change `n` to `440`?

Comment: Why do you think I guessed that? That you had changed `n` to `440` I mean?

Comment: It's probably the missing `<< "\n"; ` that's throwing you off.

Comment: Hello, I think the problem is:
auto diff = end-start;
plot << diff.count()
When I print the execution time:
std::cout << chrono::duration <double, milli> (diff).count() << " ms" << std::endl;
It prints it correctly while plotting it plots the time but without the decimals
eg: While printing 1.48242 ms while plotting 1482420
While printing 0.655735 while plotting 655735
But if you use diffe = std::chrono::duration_cast I get 0 milliseconds

Comment: Did you even count the number of conditions in that?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get you? But if you mean I should have used 
 auto diffe = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end-start);
then I have but I only wrote a fraction of it in my previous comment because of the characters limit.

Comment: Do like this: if this true: print true, if it isn't print not.

Comment: Isn't there another way to calculate the execution time of a particular instance of code rather than Chrono. I just can't seem to fix this

Comment: Replacing chrono isn't the right way to go. You must be measuring the wrong thing somehow.

Comment: Actually, I solved it: I sued this:

std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end - start;

Comment: Ok, that would give you the diff in seconds. `std::chrono::duration<double> diff_seconds = end-start; std::chrono::duration<double, std::micro> diff_microseconds = end-start; if(diff_seconds==diff_microseconds) std::cout<<"same\n";` The duration cast should result in an integer duration, so it will not be exactly the same, but fairly close.

Comment: And if you do: `std::chrono::duration<double> diffe = end-start; auto diff1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(diffe); auto diff2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end-start); if( diff1==diff2 ) std::cout << " same\n";` you'll se that the duration cast using `end-start` just simplifies it.